# How to get URI for the user profile?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I've already managed to get the user avatar URI using the following code:

```
URI uri = ComponentAccessor.getAvatarService().getAvatarURL(user, user.getName(), Avatar.Size.SMALL);
```

and it returns: `/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&amp;avatarId=10122`

My question is - is there any way of getting URI to the user profile?

Answer (score 1):

The user's profile are located at `jira.server.com/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=john`, so I guess you can get the URI you could do  something like:

```
user = "john"
user_profile_uri = "/jira/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=" + user
```

**Update**

To find the URI dynamically:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import java.net.URI
uri = new URI(ComponentManager.getInstance().getApplicationProperties().getString("jira.baseurl"))
return user_profile_uri = uri.getPath() + "ViewProfile.jspa?name=" + user
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can create the URI manually, let's say using String builder. The problem is that the first part of this URI varies on different servers - so on my machine it is `/jira/secure`, but on the production one it is slightly different. Therefore I'm looking for API that will always return the correct path.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for contribution, however it is not the answer I have been looking for. The code you provided returns the name of my computer in the local network and my code for the Avatar URI returns `localhost`... I know it will work, however it may look a bit odd. Finally I used the solution with a regular expression applied to the Avatar URI.
And I still believe that there must be API that does the trick.

Comment: @Krokodylowy have U find a better solution? If YES, can U share with me?